# Show that checking if word contains subword which doesn't contain patterns is NP-complete

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

> There are given:
>
> - finite alphabet $Σ$ with some symbols $a,b$.
> - finite list of
> - forbidden patterns natural number $n$ written unary (eg. $1^n$)
>
> Result:   Is there exists word of form $a\Sigma^*b$ with length at
> most $n$ such that it doesn't contains (as subword) any of word from
> list (list contains many words, expressed by patterns).   Show that
> this problem is NP-complete.
>
> Example to better understand patterns:
> $bbaaacb$ contains a word $a??c$, but $aacba$ doesn't contain $a??c$,
> where $?$ is some special symbol in $\Sigma$

I am not sure if I correctly understand reduction, can you help me verify it ? Also other approaches are welcome here,
My approach is following:
We reduce 3-SAT problem, let $n=6$
$(x_1 \vee \neg x_4\vee x_6)$.  For this clauses we create one pattern and put on the forbidden list:
$0??1?0$ what means that there are forbidden assigments such that it assign: $x_1=0, x_4=1, x_6=0$. Such assigment is forbidden because in this case it is not possible to satisfy this clause.
Analogously, we do with rest of clauses, so list of forbidden pattern has size $k$ where $k$ is number of clauses. Of course generating this list takes polynomial time.

Now, we can set $\Sigma=\{a,b,0,1\}, n=\text{number of variables}$  and use problem from statement of exercise to check if there exists assigment which satisfies this formula.

Comment: It isn't clear what are the allowed patterns it can solve. Now SAT aims at finding a $\{0,1\}^n$ value for $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ which satisfies a given formula involving $\land,\lor,\lnot$, so your problem is harder than SAT ie. NP-hard (in $n$).

Comment: @reuns I don't understand. What do you mean ? I did show some reduction from 3SAT to problem from exercise.

Comment: What are the allowed patterns exactly ? Given a CNF formula $f : \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ (call this a SAT patterns) SAT returns a solution $x \in \{0,1\}^n, f(x) = 1$ if it exists. Trivially your problem solves SAT. So the question is for what patterns SAT solves your problem (and if the reduction is polynomial).

Comment: From what I understand:  I show that it is possible to transform problem from 3SAT to patterns (problem from task). And you agree with it. The problem is that transform problem from task to 3SAT ? In other words the problem is to show it on both direction, no only one direction ?

Comment: Your problem is NP-complete iff it solves SAT and SAT solves it, where solves means up to polynomial reduction and change of size (equivalently your problem is NP and solves every NP problem, like an universal non-deterministic Turing machine)

Comment: Do you agree with the fact I show polynomial reduction from 3-SAT to problem from task ?

Comment: Yes. But the problem is you didn't define in general what are the allowed patterns.

Comment: I show example how patterns work. I am a bit confused. Could you answer on this question and explain how to correct this proof ?

Comment: I would generalize by saying a pattern is any function $f :\in \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ that takes $\mathcal{O}(n)$ operations to compute. Then trying all the words $x \in \{0,1\}$ and checking if $f(x) = 1$ is exactly what a non-deterministic Turing machine can do. Thus the problem $\exists x \in \{0,1\}^n, f(x) = 1$ is in NP, and as it solves SAT (with $n$ variables), it is NP-complete.

Comment: Ok, however without thinking about patterns as functions. What should I do to get fully correct solution (it can't be formal)

Comment: That's what I'm saying since the beginning : you need to define clearly what are the allowed functions called "patterns". In every case, the same argument as what I wrote applies. Go back to the definition of NP and non-deterministic TM.

Comment: *allowed functions called "patterns"* this thing is unclear for me.

Comment: For me, you doubt if there is equivalence between my problem and 3SAT.